# number theory question in a group with unknown order

Tags: rsa, group-theory, number-theory

I was reading a paper and I am struggling understanding one part of it.
Lets say we have a group $G$ of an unknown order $n$. we know that $B<n<B+C$. both B and C are large values).

we choose a random element $z \in G$. and let's say we have some prime values $B+C<e_1,e_2,...,e_l$. We Calculate $h=z^ {\prod_i e_i}$.

The claim is as $\gcd(n,\prod e_i)=1$ (which is true as each prime is greater than $n$) we can say that $h$ is uniformly distributed in $G$. How can we prove this statement?

Comment: Of course, a more efficient way to select a uniformly distributed $h \in \mathbb{G}$ would be to select a random uniformly distributed $z$..., and set $h = z$.  If you don't have a way to select a random uniformly distributed $z$, then the method in the paper isn't uniformly distributed either...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the function
$$\begin{align}
f: G&\to G\\
x&\mapsto x^{\prod_i e_i}
\end{align}$$
$f$ is [injective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function). Proof: if $f(x)=f(y)$ then $x^{\prod_i e_i}=y^{\prod_i e_i}$, thus $(x\cdot y^{-1})^{\prod_i e_i}=1$, thus the [order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_(group_theory)) $k$ of $(x\cdot y^{-1})$ is a divisor of $\prod_i e_i$. Since the order of any group element divides the group order, $k$ is also a divisor of $n$. Since $\gcd(n,\prod e_i)=1$, $k$ must be $1$. Thus $(x\cdot y^{-1})=1$, thus $x=y$.

Any injection over a finite set is a [bijection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection). It follows that $f$ is a bijection over $G$.

Thus $h$ is constructed as the image of a uniformly random element $z$ of $G$ by a bijection $f$ over $G$. Hence $h$ is a uniformly random element of $G$.

Comment: $z.z'-1$ means $z.z'^{-1}$ right?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. how it is related to the fact that gcd($n,\prod e_i$)=1?

Comment: @arman haghighi : You are right, my [former proof](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/77692/2) did not use that $\gcd(n,\prod e_i)=1$. It [now](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/77692) does. On top of that, it is much simpler.